# Performing k means clustering with a sample of the data

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm a Medical Physics Master student and i'm currently working on my Thesis. The work consists of extracting features from endoscopic images and perform classification with an SVM. I have images of 4 types. Type 1 are non cancer images, Type 2, 3 and 4 are pre-cancer images. I reduced the problem to a two class system. Class C1, type 1 images and class C2 all the others.

The method I'm using to do this is as follows: 
I extract features from each image using dense SIFT. So I obtain descriptors that are, say 128x1000 per image. So i have 1000 points in a 128-d space. The number of points for each image is different, but for simplicity lets assume 1000 per image. I divided my dataset using 50 images of class C1 and 50 of class C2 for training.

If I use 100 training images i will get data of 128x100000. If I perform k-means clustering on this data using for example 400 clusters this is a very long process. So I thought to sample this data choosing for example 10000 points uniformly spaced so that each image is represented equally. I actually get quite good results in the classification process but my doubt is if this can be done.

Will it make a big difference if I use the all data points to calculate the centers or can I sample this data for the calculations?? What value would be reasonable for the fraction of data to use??

Comment: Try to format your question properly (use of paragraph, emphasis and code highlight) and explain it more for better understanding of the problem. Also add some relevant tags if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'm new at this things.

Comment: Could you enlighten us on why the long training time is a big problem? The K-Means clustering results in a certain decision boundary (eg; If you input a image, it will decide if it detects a "healthy" image or a "cancerous" image.) The training is done only once, so the large computational time should not prove to be that big of an issue.
Working in a 128 dimensional space does incur the "curse of dimensionality". Other pattern recognition algorithms might provide better results.

Comment: Here's my idea. I extracted the descriptors using DSIFT at two scales for each image in the gray color space. I did a 3-fold CV to the data and calculated the histograms for each image. Then fed this histograms into a SVM. This procedure took me about 6 hours. My next step would be to add to this descriptor another three descriptors obtained applying DSIF independently to the R, G and B chanels. This  made the computacional time go up to 18 hours. It is a concern because I'm going to add even more descriptors to previous ones.

Comment: My thought is I could sample the data before I calculated the visual terms for the histograms. That's were the big computacional time is. Or maybe I'm concatenating the descriptors in a wrong way.

Comment: If you want to classify the data using an SVM, why are you clustering it with kmeans?

Comment: I'm calculating the histograms of each image based on the centers calculated by k-means. I then feed these histograms into the SVM. Similar to building a visual dictionary(centers by k-means) and then a vocabulary(assign the points to a center) for each image - Bag of Words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practise to run k-means on a sample *first*.

This will give you a good estimate of the final cluster centers, and by using these as seeds for the full k-means run, you may need only a single iteration afterwards.

K-means has a number of issues (curse of dimensionality, often meaningless results, choosing k), but *scalability* is not one of them. It can run really fast, 100k objects should take just a minute, unless you are using a really slow programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Anony-Mousse. So what you are saying is that I can estimate the position of the centers using a sample of the data. This will be the initial position to consider in the calculations with the full data.

Comment: I'm using vl_feat library to perform all my calculations in MATLAB. But the adding of more descriptors shouldn't increase that much the computacional time. How should I concatenate the descriptors?? For example, the Gray descriptor is extracted at two scales, so I'll have d{1} and d{2}. If I calculate other descriptors, say d1{1} ans d1{2} should I concatenate the data as descriptors=[[d{1},d{2}];d1{1},d1{2}]?? Thus increasing the number of features and not the number of points. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know what the Gray descriptor is, so I can't help you much there.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't explain my self correctly. I mean the SIFT descriptor extracted after converting the RGB image to Gray. TO that descriptor I must add other descriptors. So my question was should I concatenate this vertically or horizontally?? If I do it vertically I am incresing the number of features. If I do it horizontally I am incresing the number of points. You said previously that k-means takes less then a minute with 100k points but I have about 200k and it is taking me about 20 min. I'm using integer k-means because the data is integer, and the Elkan algorithm to perform the calculations